# German umlauts with imagepng bad output

Tags: php, image, gd

I know that the German umlauts output with PHP, can get fixed by using the

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

at the top of the PHP as shown below.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo "<h2>German umlauts: ÄÖÜäöüß</h2>";

echo "<br />";

echo "<h2>Dr. Jörg Großhaderner</h2>";

echo "<br /><br />";

echo '<img src="image.php">';
?>
```

But there is trouble displaying them on an `imagepng` code shown below for your review and test.

File: **image.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$idnum = "ER-CW-R112-DOC1297";
$title = "Dr.";
$firstname = "Jörg";
$lastname = "Großhaderner";
$ward = "Cardiothoracic Ward";
$callcode = "CW894";

// load the image from the file specified as background layout
$im = imagecreatefrompng("images/tempcard1.png");

// if there's an error, stop processing the page:
if(!$im)
{
    die("Error creating the temp card!");
}

// define some colours to use with the fonts
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// define the font and some font sizes
$fontsize = 5;

// finally, write the string:
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 130, 105, $idnum , $red);
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 110, 135, $title , $black);
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 140, 135, $firstname , $black);
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 190, 135, $lastname , $black);
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 125, 155, $ward, $black);
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 190, 175, $callcode, $blue);

// output the image
// tell the browser what we're sending it
header('Content-type: image/png; charset=utf-8');

//header('Content-type: image/png;');

// output the image as a png
imagepng($im);

// tidy up
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Files/Links:

screen_shot [image: german_imagepng.jpg]

temp_card [image: tempcard1.png]

Comment: The Content-Type has nothing to do with it; you need to make the imagestring function accept UTF-8 (possibly by specifying an appropriate font), or convert the input string to an accepted encoding (maybe ISO8859-15 for German).

Comment: Use imagettftext() instead of imagestring() and use a font that supports all characters you need.

Comment: There is a difference between what characters you actually have and in what character encoding you work internally and in what you tell the outside world what your output should be considered as. Your header function calls only do the later, but you need to take care to also work with unicode internally. Which you don't. Search for "UTF-8 all the way through"...

Comment: @Bernhard : Yabsolutely! Thank you. I will post full php for others as well. This is the accepted I will mention.

Answer (score 0):

Updated working **image.php**:

Thanks to [Bernard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4401439/bernhard) for his guiding comment.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$idnum = "ER-CW-R112-DOC1297";
$title = "Dr.";
$firstname = "Jörg";
$lastname = "Großhaderner";
$ward = "Cardiothoracic Ward";
$callcode = "CW894";

// load the image from the file specified as background layout
$im = imagecreatefrompng("images/tempcard1.png");

// if there's an error, stop processing the page:
if(!$im)
{
    die("Error creating the temp card!");
}

// define some colours to use with the fonts
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// define the font and some font sizes
$font = 'fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'; // <- This is the font supporting German umlauts
$fontsize = 17;

// finally, write the string:
/*
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 130, 105, $idnum , $red);
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 110, 135, $title , $black);
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 140, 135, $firstname , $black);
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 190, 135, $lastname , $black);
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 125, 155, $ward, $black);
imagestring($im, $fontsize, 190, 175, $callcode, $blue);
*/

/** 
*   Changed to imagettftext instead of imagestring as per Bernard's comment and works.
*   https://stackoverflow.com/users/4401439/bernhard
*/

imagettftext($im, $fontsize, 0, 90, 130, $red, $font, $idnum);
imagettftext($im, $fontsize, 0, 85, 160, $black, $font, $title);
imagettftext($im, $fontsize, 0, 125, 160, $black, $font, $firstname);
imagettftext($im, $fontsize, 0, 175, 160, $black, $font, $lastname);
imagettftext($im, $fontsize, 0, 90, 195, $black, $font, $ward);
imagettftext($im, $fontsize, 0, 160, 220, $blue, $font, $callcode);

// output the image
// tell the browser what we're sending it
header('Content-type: image/png;');

// output the image as a png
imagepng($im);

// tidy up
imagedestroy($im);
```

Hope it helps others as well.

Screenshot:
[image: german.jpg]